# how to get labels in multilabel facial recognition

Tags: keras, deep-learning, label, face-recognition, multilabel-classification

I used the `ImagedataGenerator` and `flow from directory` to train a CNN model for the task and saved into a `.h5` file. While prediction the logits or an array of numbers are being displayed and not the labels.

I need the labels to be displayed while prediction.

One possible way I tried was to reassign value of each logit to the desired label or string but I think it could be a tediuos task

what I got:

```
[[1 0 0]]
```

what I need:
"steve rogers"

Comment: PutText(currentImageFrame, name + " ", new System.Drawing.Point(facesDetected[i].X, facesDetected[i].Y), Emgu.CV.CvEnum.FontFace.HersheyComplex, 1.0, new Bgr(255, 255, 0).MCvScalar);  We use like that. You should search something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You need the string labels for the predictions you receive from the Keras model. That's easy using `np.argmax(x, axis=0 )`

If `pred` is the output of the Keras model ( predictions ) then,

```
import numpy as np

max_indices = np.argmax( pred , axis=1 )
```

Define a Python `list` which has the `str` labels. Like,

```
labels = [ 'NAME1' , 'NAME2' , 'NAME3' ]
```

Then, we iterate over the `max_indices` array and fetch the objects from `labels`,

```
for i in max_indices:
    print( 'Label is {}'.format( labels[i] ) )
```